# CI, How to get data call by id from database?

Tags: codeigniter

**+ This my Model:**

```
public function call_by_id($where){
        $this->db->select('*');
        $this->db->from($this->table);
        $this->db->where($where);
        $query = $this->db->get();
        return $query->result();
    }
```

**+ This my Controller:**

```
public function index()
    {   
        $data = array();
        $w = '';
        $data['call_id'] = $this->mo_product->call_by_id($w);

        $this->load->view('...', $data);
    }
```

**+ And I want to call on view like :**

```
$call_id[$id]->username;
```

Comment: yes it should be like that. but how can get some data from table. that my purpose want to call it by id. but I don't know to code it ? help !!!
thank

Answer (score 0):

- In model, you put $where in wrong place. Put it as parameter => `call_by_id($where)`
- In controller, `$w` should be an integer just like your id's value, ex: `$w = 1;`. And you don't need to write `$data = array()`.

**+ This my Model:**

```
public function call_by_id($where){
        $this->db->select('*');
        $this->db->from($this->table);
        $this->db->where('id', $where);
        $query = $this->db->get();
        return $query->result();
    }
```

**+ This my Controller:**

```
public function index()
    {   
        $w = 1; //we need to set value for spesific id
        //we can only call the model's function in controller 
        $data['call_id'] = $this->mo_product->call_by_id($w);

        $this->load->view('...', $data);
    }
```

**+ And I want to call on view like :**

```
// view is just to show the data after we call the model's function in controller
print_r($call_id);
```

Try it, hope it can helps :)

Comment: thank for help. but it still not work then I follow you. 
please kindly to help me more ? 
thank

Comment: From where you get `$w` value?

Comment: I just start with codeigniter. So I not know well with this. Then I have show you my code , I just want to get data from my syntax on the view. ex: $call_id['5']->product_name; that it I just want like this. thank

Comment: How can I get it ?

Comment: Do you mean you want to call the `call_by_id()` in view?

Comment: if I use $call_id as foreach I think It will work.but foreach it will loop all from table. I don't want like this. I need some value from table not all. So please tell me more ? 
thank !!!

Comment: How's your `print_r` result?

Comment: It show :
Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [product_id] => 5 [product_company_fk] => 8 [product_name] => Dell [product_category_fk] => 5 [product_code] => 001 [product_series] => [product_price] => 350.00 [product_description] =>
test dell product
[product_status] => published [updater] => 1 [created_dt] => 2017-01-20 05:23:41 [updated_dt] => 2017-01-20 05:23:41 [deleted_dt] => 2017-02-05 04:48:20 ) )

Comment: I see that your result is only one row. So, you can call spesific field by call: `$call_id[0]->product_name` in view for example.

Comment: I still not understand with you. print_r($call_id) it work but we set it on controller value is $w = 1; so it will work where id = 1; And another still not work.

Comment: I see. You wanna get spesific field based on spesific id right? One more thing you need to do is, how to set value of $w and your value must be based on database. So why when you set its value to 1, it shows the result? Because in your database id=1 is exist

Comment: Now follow you on $call_id[id]->product_name still not work. please kindly help me to complete it.

Comment: Let's have some practice, first `$call_id[0]->product_name` should be done in view, how's view?

Comment: I have try it and it work but it just array[0] of table not id

Comment: Make sure if the print_r result still this:Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [product_id] => 5 [product_company_fk] => 8 [product_name] => Dell [product_category_fk] => 5 [product_code] => 001 [product_series] => [product_price] => 350.00 [product_description] => test dell product [product_status] => published [updater] => 1 [created_dt] => 2017-01-20 05:23:41 [updated_dt] => 2017-01-20 05:23:41 [deleted_dt] => 2017-02-05 04:48:20 ) ) . **Then you can replace print_r code with `echo $call_id[0]->product_name`**

Comment: I am happy to hear that, happy coding!

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this

```
public function call_by_id($where){
    $this->db->where('your_column_name', $where);
    $query = $this->db->get($this->table);
    return $query->result_array();
}
```

On controller

```
public function index()
{   

    $data['results'] = array();

    $w = '1'; // some id

    $data['results'] = $this->mo_product->call_by_id($w);

    $this->load->view('...', $data);
}
```

View

```
foreach ($results as $result) {
    echo $result['something_from_database'];
}
```

> **Update for only one value use row_array();**

https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/results.html#CI_DB_result::row_array

Model

```
public function call_by_id($where){
    $this->db->where('your_column_name', $where);
    $query = $this->db->get($this->table);
    return $query->row_array();
}
```

Controller

```
public function index()
{   

    $w = '1'; // some id

    $caller_data = $this->mo_product->call_by_id($w);

    $data['caller_id'] = $caller_data['caller_id'];

    $this->load->view('...', $data);
}
```

View

```
<?php echo $caller_id;?>
```

Comment: OK in this case, Just only one value to show if i have 5 or 6 How code?